# Chatbot with node.js and python for NLP

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, nlp, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm actually working on a chatbot project which must talk 2 languages **(Dialectic Moroccan and french)** , i'm willing to build the bot with node.js and host it in a server and build an NLP with python from scratch  then link both of codes .

Do you have any idea of how can i integrate python code to a **node.js** code?

Comment: The  [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) module may be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an Express server with endpoints that make calls to your NLP backend (written in Python) and retrieve their outputs.

### How it could be implemented

**Some Assumptions**

Here, I'll assume that you intend to send the user's input text from your NodeJS server to your Python NLP backend to be translated & sent back to your NodeJS server as a valid response.

**The Plan**

Let's say you have an endpoint on your Express server called `http://localhost:3000/Morrocan_NLP?text=mytexttotranslate`. We're going to feed the query parameter `text = "mytexttotranslate"` to a Python script that'll receive it at the `/Morrocan_NLP` endpoint. This Python script will then process that piece of text and send it back to your NodeJS Express server.

To do that, you could set up a valid route in your NodeJS Express app and **invoke the relevant Python script from that using a child process** Here's a hypothetical code example to showcase this interaction:

```js
// Setting up your Express server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Step 1: 
// Set up the /Morrocan_NLP Express route
app.get('/Morrocan_NLP', invokePythonMorrocanTranslator);

// Step 2: 
// Create a callback function that handles requests to the '/Morrocan_NLP' endpoint
function invokePythonMorrocanTranslator(req, res) {

    // Importing Node's 'child_process' module to spin up a child process. 
    // There are other ways to create a child process but we'll use the 
    // simple spawn function here.
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

    // The spawned python process which takes 2 arguments, the name of the 
    // python script to invoke and the query parameter text = "mytexttotranslate"
    var process = spawn('python', 
        [
            "./morrocan_nlp.py"
            req.query.text
        ]
    );

    // Step 3:
    // Listen for data output from stdout, in this case, from "morrocan_nlp.py"
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

        // Sends the output from "morrocan_nlp.py" back to the user
        res.send(data.toString());

    });

}
```

In your Python script (just a hypothetical one) that does Morrocan translation called `morrocan_nlp.py`, you'd have something like this to receive & process the NodeJS server's query and return the result to it.

```py
import sys

# This is how you'll receive the queries from your NodeJS server
# Notice that sys.argv[1] refers to the 2nd argument of the list passed 
# into the spawn('python', ...) function in your NodeJS server code above
text_from_node_server = str(sys.argv[1])

# perform_translation here is a function I made up that 
# translates any text into Morrocan
translated_text = perform_translation(text_from_node_server)

# return your processed text to the NodeJS server via stdout
print(translated_text)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

### External resources

This is a basic way of communicating between NodeJS server <--> Python script which, however, might not be the most scalable and efficient way if you're builing a large-scale application. So I'd like to recommend you to refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@HolmesLaurence/integrating-node-and-python-6b8454bfc272) which contains a step-by-step tutorial on how to integrate NodeJS and Python in other more reliable ways as well. I really hope this has helped you or any other person reading this to get started!

Comment: Thank you alot i had this problem of how to communicate between both of codes